# Left Join with further Conditions/Joining

Tags: mysql, left-join, inner-join

How to handle situation where you want to Use a `Left Join`, because the data may or may not exist. But if the `Left Join` does find some data, you want to limit that left-joined data further by joining the left-joined data on another table? (Without removing the original data from the results).

I think it might require a further `Join`, `Where`, or subquery.

Here's what I tried:

```
SELECT users.*, failed_logins.*
FROM users
LEFT JOIN failed_logins ON failed_logins.user_id = users.user_id
INNER JOIN banned ON banned.ip_address = failed_logins.ip_address
```

But this causes no data to be displayed if there is no data in `banned` that matches `failed_logins`.

If there's a matching row in `banned`, we want to include the row from `banned` and `failed_logins`. Otherwise the row from `failed_logins` and `banned` should be excluded. But the data grabbed from `users` should always be included.

Comment: your question is not clear to me .. please update your query and add a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Why user.user_id should be equal to emails.email_id ? Maybe you can add tables structure so we can help you

Comment: Thanks for the comments, updated the question to be as clear as I could. Will add example data later if needed, but have to head out for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition in the INNER JOIN is going to require `failed_logins.ip_address` to have a non-NULL value. Any rows with a NULL value for that column are going to be excluded.  And that is going to negate the "outerness" of the join to `failed_logins`.  (Any row in `users` that doesn't have a matching row in `failed_logins`, the outer join will invent a dummy matching row from `failed_logins`, all of the columns in the matching dummy row will be NULL.

So, we would need a way to allow `NULL` values of `failed_logins.ip_address` to be returned.

One option would be to make that inner join an outer join. That is, replace `INNER` with `LEFT`.

There are some other ways to approach this type of issue. But it really depends on what resultset we want to return. Example data and expected results would go a long ways to clarifying the specification.

---

EDIT

After re-reading the question, it's still not clear what result we want returned. Why are we needing to look at the `banned` table? "to filter the data if it does exist" doesn't really explain the specification.

If there's a matching row in `banned`, we want to *exclude* the row from the resultset? Or, we want to return rows where a matching row does not exist in `banned`.

---

FOLLOWUP

Do the join between `failed_logins` and `banned` first, in an inline view (or, *derived table* to use the MySQL parlance). And then do an outer join between `users` and the derived table.

As an example:

```
SELECT users.*
     , fl.*
  FROM users
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT f.user_id
              , f.ip_address 
           FROM failed_logins f
           JOIN banned b
             ON b.ip_address = f.ip_address
       ) fl
    ON fl.user_id = users.user_id
 ORDER BY users.user_id, fl.ip_address
```

Given `failed_logins` sample data:

```
 user_id      ip_address
 ----------   ------------
     111      127.0.0.1
     111      192.168.0.1
     222      127.0.0.1
     333      192.168.0.1
     444      4.4.4.4
```

and `banned` sample data

```
 ip_address
 ----------
 127.0.0.1
```

and assuming `users` contains five rows, 111 thru 555, the query should return:

```
user_id  user_id  ip_address
-------  -------  ----------
111      111      127.0.0.1
222      222      127.0.0.1
333      (null)   (null)
444      (null)   (null)
555      (null)   (null)
```

If this doesn't meet the specification, please consider providing some sample data (including examples of cases of rows that should and should not be returned), along with the  expected output.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, updated the question to be as clear as I could. Will add example data later if needed, but have to head out for now.